# Copy latest file from one server to another at specific time

Tags: file-copy, scheduling

I want to copy a latest file of file.txt from Linux server A to server B at a specific time  .

It may be a duplicate question but i could not find the solution for this. Everyday I need to wait util  a specific time to run the scp command. I'm new to linux please help me.

Comment: Do you have public key authentication via ssh from server A to server B?

Comment: Yes have the authentication

Answer (score 2):

On server A, add a cronjob with `crontab -e`:

```
30 10 * * * scp /path/to/file user@serverb:/path/to/directory
```

You can also use:

```
30 10 * * * rsync -avp /path/to/file user@serverb:/path/to/directory
```

Make sure to have a new line afterwards by pressing ENTER.

That will create a cronjob that uses rsync to copy the file from the server A to server B at 10:30 AM. You can alter it for the time that you want.

Comment: Hi Nasir, Thank you for your quick response. Due to security reason we don’t use crontab function. Is there any other way?

Comment: @unix.thula There are no security risks that result from running a cron job unless there is something in the cron job that does so which in this case, there isn't. There is no other way to run a script at a certain time unless you are going to go in and run an `at` job every single day where the tedium wouldn't be worth it. Plenty of of companies and organizations do what you are trying to do using `cron` and there aren't any issues with security or anything else.

Comment: While `cron` itself may not be frowned upon, letting non-root users create their own crontab is sometimes considered a risk as that's one way malware can establish persistence, or that means users can abuse system resources by starting their own service this way. Creating an entry in `/etc/cron.d` or use systemd timers may be another approach. If /etc/cron.allow doesn't allow ordinary users to create crontabs