# Copy folder from one Linux server to another - cloning files onto a backup server

Tags: linux, rsync, scp

I would like to copy selected data files/folders from our a production server to a backup server.  I want to do this every night at midnight.  The servers are basically side-by-side, on the same internal network.

I have read this reference [Copy latest file from one server to another at specific time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591316/copy-latest-file-from-one-server-to-another-at-specific-time) and I "think" I understand most of it, but for a few details:

- the user for the CRON job must have SSH authentication to the backup server box, similar to if I were to just SSH into that box. Correct?
- The CRON job will run even if that user is not logged on?
- this folder copy is meant to totally overwrite the target folder and its files  completely.  OK?
- are the commands in the reference complete and correct for my situation?

  ```
  30 10 * * * scp /path/to/file user@serverb:/path/to/directory
  30 10 * * * rsync -avp /path/to/file user@serverb:/path/to/directory
  ```
- which is better, scp or rsync ?

Comment: (1) Yes, you will need ssh authentication between the boxes without a passphrase needed. (2) the cron job does not depend on any particular user being logged in. (3) It will not overwrite the destination folder's files, it will only update files that are newer in the source. (4 and 5) the rsync is unnecessary if you run scp first. I would get rid of `scp` and use only `rsync`.

Comment: Thanks.  If I really want it to overwrite, is that an option?  Also, I guess I was not fully clear for items 4&5.  I was only planing to run one or the other of the commands.  I'll take you recommendation for rsync, thanks again..